# Utility function is given as $U = \sqrt{XY}$ find

Tags: microeconomics, utility

Matthew has a utility function $U = \sqrt{XY}$ where X represents hot dogs and Y represents apples. He has an income of $20.

Hot dogs cost \$1.00 and apples cost \$1.25

**Part (i) asks:** Matthew's utility fucntion implies that the marginal utility of apples is $0.5 \sqrt{\frac{X}{Y}}$ and the marginal utility of hotdogs is $0.5 \sqrt{\frac{Y}{X}}$. How many apples will he buy? How many hot dogs will he buy?

**Part (ii) asks:** This year, the price of hot dogs rise to \$3 each while Mathew’s income is unchanged. Mathew’s father decides to help him by giving him a gift of \$20. Consider an indifference curve-budget line diagram with hot dogs on the x-axis and apples on the y-axis. After Mathew gets the \$20 gift, will his new budget line lie above, lie below, or pass through his initial optimum? Justify your choice. Will Mathew be better or worse off than he was last year?

### What have I done?

I'm pretty stuck on this. There aren't really any similar examples from me to draw upon from our course literature.

Perhaps the formulas $\dfrac{MU_x}{MU_y} = \dfrac{P_x}{P_y}$ and $I = P_x \cdot x + P_y \cdot y$ might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than write a complete answer, I am going to post a couple of hints that will hopefully get you underway.

---

For part (i), note that

- You have two equations: $\dfrac{MU_x}{MU_y} = \dfrac{P_x}{P_y}$ and $I = P_x \cdot x + P_y \cdot y$.
- Since we know $MU_x$, $MU_y$, $P_x$, $P_y$, and $I$, these two equations contain two unknowns.
- Usually, so long as we have at least as many equations as there are unknown variables, we can find the value of those variables by simultaneously solving the equations.
- the $x$ in $I = P_x \cdot x + P_y \cdot y$ is the quantity of hot dogs that you are asked to compute in part (i), so ultimately you are going to have to solve for the value of this variable.
- my suggestion would therefore be that you try substituting into your two equations all of the things whose value you know and then try solving for $x$.

---

Since a budget line is a straight line, it is characterised by an intercept, $c$, and a slope, $m$.

If you think about drawing this line geometrically then you should recognise that

- the intercept is the amount of $y$ you could afford if you didn't buy any $x$ and spent all of your available money on $y$.
- the slope is the number of units of $y$ you would have to give up to save enough money to afford one more unit of $x$.

Once you know the slope and the intercept, you can write down the equation for your budget line, $y=mx+c$, and answering part (ii) is then just a matter of algebra.

Comment: Thank you. For the formula $\dfrac{MU_x}{MU_y} = \dfrac{P_x}{P_y}$ I'm unsure how to get $MU_x$ and $MU_y$. When using $0.5 \sqrt{\dfrac{Y}{X}}$ is X and Y \$1.00 and \$1.25 respectively? OR is it how many of X and Y Matthew can afford with his budget of \$20. Namely, is $X = 20$ and $Y=16$? Thanks again. Once I know this, it's just easy substitution I think (as you said).

Comment: @GeekbabeTV You don't need to do either. Just leave the values of $x$ and $y$ undefined and, once you substitute the expression for marginal utility into $MU_x/MU_y$, as well as substituting in the values for prices and income you will find that you have two equations that depend only on $x$ and $y$. Then you can solve for those two variables. Note that there appears to be a typo: $x$ and $X$ are actually the same variable.